# Send a question or thanks letter after receiving a notification of receipt of application?

Tags: etiquette, job-search, email, faculty-application

After applying to some faculty positions, some professors send emails (not the automatic ones) that they have received the application and ask if the applicants have any questions. Should the applicant raise any question or maybe send a thank you reply for the notification to show their interest? Or just ignore and wait.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Saying "thanks, I don't have any questions at the moment." Would be appropriate and it would also be appropriate and perhaps show more interest in the position if you did ask a question or two about the department or the position.  For example, you might ask if anyone from the department will be attending an upcoming conference that you are going to.  However, you don't want to be presumptuous, so detailed questions about salary, benefits, etc. are not appropriate at this early stage.